# How to remove completely Oracle Data Provider from .net

Tags: asp.net, oracle11g, odp.net

I had tried to install Oracle Data Provider for .NET framework but the installation was failed. After that I was unable to run the projects, it gives configuration error.

[image: Error shown while running the project]

How can I resolve this issues.

Comment: Have you tried simply removing that line from your configuration?

Comment: @Kiran Shahi the line in your config tells the environment to go look up a package, remove it and it should be fixed.

Comment: There are many lines related to Oracle in master.config

Comment: I removed the packages related to oracle but problem was not solved.

Comment: Did you remove the lines related to Oracle from your config? Obviously if those lines refer to packages that are deleted they're going to cause issues.

Comment: Thank you friends, I have removed machine.config and renamed machine.config.default to machine.config. It works for me

Comment: That's really not a good way of going about it, because you might lose other useful things from your machine.config. Why couldn't you just remove any Oracle related lines from your config file?

Comment: Your screenshot shows "Oracle.Web.Management.OracleWebEventProvider" as the cause of the problem. That means you installed "Oracle Providers for ASP.NET" using the Oracle installer and then did not properly uninstall it.

Comment: I tried to install but installation was not complete. And removed that program from control panel but I can't uninstall it completely.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the `Oracle data provider` as  follows :

1. On the Start menu (for Windows 8, right-click the screen's
   bottom-left corner), click Control Panel, and then, under Programs,
   do one of the following: Windows Vista/7/8: Click Uninstall a
   Program. Windows XP: Click Add or Remove Programs.
2. When you find the program Oracle Data Provider for .NET Help, click
   it, and then do one of the following: Windows Vista/7/8: Click
   Uninstall.
3. Windows XP: Click the Remove or Change/Remove tab (to the right of
   the program). Follow the prompts. A progress bar shows you how long
   it will take to remove Oracle Data Provider for .NET Help

For More_info check [this](http://www.shouldiremoveit.com/Oracle-Data-Provider-for-NET-Help-9472-program.aspx) Source

There is a Software Removal tool for Windows , i haven't tested it , but you can get it from [here](http://softuninstall.com/remove-oracle-data-provider-for-net-help.html)